# How to align right last flexbox item when margin-left: auto doesn't work because of flex-wrap: wrap?

Tags: css, flexbox

I tried to have right aligned image in my flexbox container (due to mobile first approach I use flex-wrap: wrap and now I have two columns with 100% width, that will change widths to 50% on some breakpoint) and strangely it works only when I use text-align: right.

I tried margin-left: auto on the img or justify-content: space-between on parent, but img is still left positioned by this approach.

If anyone could help me find the better solution, I'd be happy.

Here is what I have:

```
<div class="hero">

    <div class="hero__col hero__message">

        <h1>Hello world</h1>

    </div>

    <div class="hero__col hero__image">

        <!-- You need at least 10 reputation to post images -->

    </div>

</div>

<style>
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.hero {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: #ddd;
}

.hero__col {
    width: 100%;
}

.hero__message {
    text-align: center;
}

.hero__image {
    text-align: right;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Auto margins do not work on inline elements, you would need to make the image `block`.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried margin-left: auto on the img

Auto margins do not work on inline elements.

You need to make the image `display: block` for that to have the desired effect.